# how can I call my button value that is on another page?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm new on Reactjs and i came across this issue, i made the function of an input on page number 1, where I type a numeric value, I call this function on the second page where I call the function and where I also define the paypal parameters:

Function input of the first page:

```
function ButtonBID() {
  return (
    <>
      <div class="form__group field">
        <input
          type="input"
          class="form__field"
          placeholder="Name"
          name="bid"
          id="name"
          required
        />
        <label for="name" class="form__label">
          Bid now!
        </label>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Then i call this function on the second page:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Navbar from '../../Components/Navbar/Navbar'
import Video from '../../Asssets/Video/Video.mp4'
import Table from '../../Components/Table/Table'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { FirstPositionButton, ButtonBID } from '../../Components/Buttons/Button/Button'

function RankingHome() {

  const paypal = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    window.paypal.Buttons({
      createOrder: (data, actions, err) => {
        return actions.order.create({
          intent: "CAPTURE",
          purchase_units: [{
            description: 'Cool looking table',
            amount: {
              currency_code: "EUR",
              value: //**** i would to call the input value here ***//
                    }
          }]
        })
      },
      onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
        const order = await actions.order.capture()
        console.log(order)
      },
      onError: (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }).render(paypal.current)
  }, [])
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <HeroContainer>
        <HeroBg>
          <VideoBg src={Video} type="video/mp4" autoPlay loop muted playsInline />
        </HeroBg>
        <HeroContent>
          <HeroItems>
            <HeroH1>Who will win?</HeroH1>
            <Table />
            <div className="flexati">
              <FirstPositionButton />
              <ButtonBID />
              <Link to='/Pay'>
                <i class="far fa-check onClick={paypal}"></i>
                <div ref={paypal}></div>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </HeroItems>
        </HeroContent>
      </HeroContainer>
    </>
  )
}

export default RankingHome
```

I would like to be able to take the value of the 'textbox' and finally pass it as a parameter inside the paypal 'amount', thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `RankingHome` component you should declare a state to store the input value of textbox;

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function RankingHome() {
  const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    window.paypal.Buttons({
      createOrder: (data, actions, err) => {
        return actions.order.create({
          intent: "CAPTURE",
          purchase_units: [{
            description: 'Cool looking table',
            amount: {
              currency_code: "EUR",
              value: //**** i would to call the input value here ***//
                        }
          }]
        })
      },
      onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
        const order = await actions.order.capture()
        console.log(order)
      },
      onError: (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }).render(paypal.current)
  }, [])

  // Your code continues here
  // To the place <ButtonBID /> has been called and edit it this way.
  <ButtonBID text={textValue} setText={setTextValue} />
  // Your code continues here.
}
```

In `ButtonBID` component

```
function ButtonBID(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div class="form__group field">
        <input
          value={props.text}
          onChange={props.setText}
          type="input"
          className="form__field"
          placeholder="Name"
          name="bid"
          id="name"
          required
        />
        <label for="name" class="form__label">
          Bid now!
        </label>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default ButtonBID;
```